# CalledProcessError: Command '['bash', '-c', 'python generate_tfrecord.py .... ]' returned non-zero exit status 1. error

Tags: python, subprocess

currently learning deep learning in collab and got error like

> ```
>      21 import subprocess
>      22 bashCommand = "python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=data/train.csv  --output_path=data/train.record"
> ---> 23 output = subprocess.check_output(['bash','-c', bashCommand])
>      24 print(output)
>      25
> ```

```
CalledProcessError: Command '['bash', '-c', 'python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=data/train.csv 
--output_path=data/train.record']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

while my code are

```
import subprocess 
bashCommand = "python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=data/train.csv --output_path=data/train.record" 
output = subprocess.check_output(['bash','-c', bashCommand]) 
print(output)

bashCommand = "python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=data/test.csv --output_path=data/test.record" 
output = subprocess.check_output(['bash','-c', bashCommand]) 
print(output)
```

anyone have a clue what is this or how to fix it? thank youu

Comment: Does `generate_tfrecord.py` exist in the current directory?

Comment: @JohnGordon i did sir, sorry for the late reply